# correct fix for warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules?

Tags: c++

Given:

```
inline uint16_t Hash3_x86_16(const void* key, int len, uint32_t seed)
{
  uint32_t hash32;
  Hash3_x86_32(key, len, seed, &hash32);
  return (reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(&hash32)[1] | reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(&hash32)[0]);
}
```

What is the correct/best fix to prevent GCC from giving the following warning?

> warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing
> rules

Comment: Bitshifting as @273K answered would be best. `bit_cast` could also work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bit shifting:

```
return static_cast<uint16_t>(hash32 | (hash32 >> 16));
```